# Is there a way to install Semantic-UI under node_modules folder?

Tags: npm, semantic-ui

Just noticed there's a new version of Semantic-UI and immediately wanted to upgrade. Now all the previous minor upgrades of 2.2.x worked fine with `npm update` but jump to 2.3 stopped working flushing all the previous build and forcing to restart everything from beginning (selecting project etc.). My project is not npm project at all, just has MVC logic and want to compile my own bundle of css to use in my views. I re-use the distributed js from the package. Any suggestions how may I kick in `semantic-ui` project with all default distribution inside `node_modules` folder?

Here's the trace of what I'm usually getting:

```
Installing
------------------------------
Installing to node_modules/semantic-ui
Copying UI definitions
[20:07:55] 'create install files' errored after 8 ms
[20:07:55] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat './src/definitions'
    at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:968:11)
    at Object.exports.copyDirSyncRecursive (/path/to/project/node_modules/wrench-sui/lib/wrench.js:244:23)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/path/to/project/node_modules/semantic-ui/tasks/install.js:302:12)
    at module.exports (/path/to/project/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/path/to/project/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/path/to/project/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/path/to/project/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
    at runNextSet (/path/to/project/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:106:15)
    at Gulp.onTaskEnd (/path/to/project/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:95:4)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:165:20)
[20:07:55] 'install' errored after 14 s
[20:07:55] Error in plugin 'run-sequence(create install files)'
Message:
    ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat './src/definitions'
Details:
    errno: -2
    code: ENOENT
    syscall: stat
    path: ./src/definitions
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as being out-dated. I get entirely different errors regarding semantic-ui 2.4 version so.. - definitely not using 2.2 -> 2.3 step which was problematic here

Answer (score 0):

As I finished my question draft and started reviewing, instantly thought of a test case: why not try full path. That worked. Don't want this experience to go wasted and sharing my struggle and waste of time here.

```
Installing
------------------------------
Installing to /path/to/project/node_modules/semantic-ui
Copying UI definitions
Copying UI themes
Copying gulp tasks
Adding theme files
Creating gulpfile.js
Creating site theme folder /path/to/project/path/to/project/node_modules/semantic-ui/src/site/
[20:22:36] Starting 'create theme.config'...
Adjusting @siteFolder to:  site/
Creating src/theme.config (LESS config) /path/to/project/path/to/project/node_modules/semantic-ui/src/theme.config
[20:22:36] Finished 'create theme.config' after 13 ms
[20:22:36] Starting 'create semantic.json'...
Creating config file (semantic.json) /path/to/project/semantic.json
[20:22:36] Finished 'create semantic.json' after 10 ms
[20:22:36] Finished 'create install files' after 103 ms
[20:22:36] Starting 'clean up install'...

 Setup Complete! 
 Installing Peer Dependencies. Please refrain from ctrl + c... 
 After completion navigate to /path/to/project/node_modules/semantic-ui and run "gulp build" to build
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ semantic-ui@2.3.0
added 22 packages in 55.506s
```

**Note!** Script automatically installs web for you in `path/to/project` which looks like double copying but it is not. Had to just delete that from source and check of any changes in `theme.config`. Other scripts already in place and was good to go.